# Get url of selected gallery images?

Tags: plugins, gallery

I'm implementing a gallery upload to my plugin, and I've set up an image gallery upload with:

```
function upload_gallery_button(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $input_field = $('#portfolio_gallery');
    var ids = $input_field.val();
    var gallerysc = '[gallery ids="' + ids + '" link="file"]';
    wp.media.gallery.edit(gallerysc).on('update', function(g) {
        var id_array = [];
        $.each(g.models, function(id, img){
            id_array.push(img.id);
        });
        var ids = id_array.join(",");
        ids = ids.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
        $input_field.val(ids);
    });
```

When I click on upload button, the gallery upload opens, I select the images, and in my hidden input field I get the id's of the images that I can put in the gallery shortcode. But this only works when I save my page. Is it possible to pull the url's of the selected images so that the images are added instantly?

I don't need the gallery shortcode, I can create my own html markup for images in the metabox, but I'd like to have images shown as I add them.

I've tried changing `id_array.push(img.id);` to `id_array.push(img.link);` and `id_array.push(img.url);` but no luck.

The information on this is sparse, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
id_array.push(img.attributes.url);
```

This will return url's instead of id's.

Comment: Another option is `img.get('url')`